# Do I put a hyphen between the number and unit?

Tags: hyphenation, numbers, measuring-units

For example, in the sentence:

> I enforced a 60 minute time limit.

Should it be:

> I enforced a 60-minute time limit.

Which one is correct?

Comment: @Clare 'stylebook'?

Comment: I don't know if that's a true duplicate, Laurel... OP is asking about 60-minute and your question is about a 5-min.... All joking aside, the two answers represent what two different style guides would say.